# Table isn't centered properly in Module

Tags: joomla-3.x, jhtml

My table in my portfolio module isn't centering properly. In chrome it is a bit too much to the left when in firefox it's a bit too much to the right. Any ideas? Here is my html code for the portfolio.

```
<p style="text-align: center;"> </p>
<table style="height: 265px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" width="1013">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
<td style="text-align: center;">
<p><img src="images/quest_design_web_gallery_header.png" alt="" /></p>
<p> </p>
</td>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
<td><a href="img/image-1.jpg" data-lightbox="web" data-title="This is first image caption"><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="images/thumbnail.png" alt="Thumbnail" border="0" /></a></td>
<td><a href="img/image-2.jpg" data-lightbox="web" data-title="This is second image caption"><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="images/thumbnail.png" alt="Thumbnail" border="0" /></a></td>
<td><a href="img/image-3.jpg" data-lightbox="web" data-title="This is third image caption"><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="images/thumbnail.png" alt="Thumbnail" border="0" /></a></td>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
<td style="text-align: left;">
<p> </p>
<p><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="images/quest_design_design_gallery_header.png" alt="" /></p>
<p> </p>
</td>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
<td><a href="img/image-1.jpg" data-lightbox="design" data-title="This is first image caption"><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="images/thumbnail.png" alt="Thumbnail" border="0" /></a></td>
<td><a href="img/image-2.jpg" data-lightbox="web" data-title="This is second image caption"><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="images/thumbnail.png" alt="Thumbnail" border="0" /></a></td>
<td><a href="img/image-3.jpg" data-lightbox="web" data-title="This is third image caption"><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="images/thumbnail.png" alt="Thumbnail" border="0" /></a></td>
<td>   </td>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
<td style="text-align: center;">
<p> </p>
<p><img src="images/quest_design_image_gallery_header.png" alt="" /></p>
</td>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
<td><br /><a href="img/image-1.jpg" data-lightbox="image" data-title="This is first image caption"><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="images/thumbnail.png" alt="Thumbnail" border="0" /></a></td>
<td><br /><a href="img/image-2.jpg" data-lightbox="image" data-title="This is second image caption"><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="images/thumbnail.png" alt="Thumbnail" border="0" /></a></td>
<td><br /><a href="img/image-3.jpg" data-lightbox="image" data-title="This is third image caption"><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="images/thumbnail.png" alt="Thumbnail" border="0" /></a></td>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
<td> </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<p style="text-align: center;"> </p>
```

Any help would be great.

http://www.webbmaster.com.au/web-programs/questdesign/index.php/folio

Comment: Did you check/reset explicitly your paddings and Margins on the container element?

Answer (score 1):

There might be some styling in your template CSS file that is overriding the styling for the table.

By default, the following would work:

```
table {
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Of course you should assign a class or ID to your table and target that instead.

Or you can wrap you table in a `div` like so:

```
<div style="text-align:center">    
   <table style="display: inline-table;">  

   </table>
</div>
```